# Model.solr_search not working for geospatial filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, solr, geospatial, sunspot-solr

I have configured `sunspot-2.1.1`.

**Problem**

- I want to search All products within 20 miles radius and below is my code to do that for `Product` model

  ```
           Product.search do
              fulltext(params[:search][:keyword])
              order_by_geodist(:location, current_user.lat, current_user.lng)
              with(:location).in_radius(current_user.lat, current_user.lng, mile_to_km)

              paginate page: params[:page], per_page: GlobalConstant::SEARCH_RESULT_PER_PAGE
            end
  ```

**NOTE: above code is working properly in development environment it is not workingin production envionment. I have tried reindexing solr also, but no luck :(**

And I have added below code in other than search page where I am displaying radius based products lists and it is working:

```
             Sunspot.search [Product] do
                without(:sale_status, 'draft')
                with(:user_id, current_user.id)
                unless current_user.location.blank?
                  order_by_geodist(:location, current_user.lat, current_user.lng)
                  with(:location).in_radius(current_user.lat, current_user.lng, (mile_to_km))
                end

                paginate page: params[:page], per_page: GlobalConstant::TIMELINE_PER_PAGE
              end
```

What am I missing, why is it not working in production environment and is working in development environment.?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am really sorry to open this issue, I am stupid who have created `searches_controller_backup.rb` which had old code that was not configured with `geospatial` filter functionality.

The problem was **everything was working** but because rails was loading searches_controller codes from backup file, it was suppose to looks like it was not working.

With that note, above both codes are working perfectly without any issue....so `Model.solr_search` have nothing to do with `geospatial filter` not working.

Removing backup file or changing extension to other than `.rb` fixed my problem